# Get movie details from online database

Tags: database, vb.net, winforms, imdb, movies

I recently spent a little while attempting to create an application, that could go through large movie collections and download all the details pertaining to them (Title, Year, Rating, Classification, Runtime, Plot Summary, Genre).

After spending a little while on it, and numerous questions on SO, I had what I wanted. To provide a complete and detailed explanation for anyone else wanting to develop a similar thing, below you may find my code.

To give credit where credit is due,

- Thanks to http://www.omdbapi.com for the database API
- Thanks to the SO users who asked/answered questions that I had along the way (First time using Regex, HttpWebRequest and Writing RTF files)

Good luck!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This project requires the following controls with the corresponding values:

- 3 Labels (PercentComplete, NumberOfMovies, NumberOfSuccessful)

  - PercentComplete.Text = "0%"
  - NumberOfMovies.Text = "Number of movies in directory: "
  - NumberOfSuccessful.Text = "Number of successful scrapes: "
- 1 RichTextBox (Consolus)

  - DetectURLS = False
  - Foreground = Lime
  - Background = Black
  - Font = Consolas, 12pt
- 3 Buttons (SelectSource, SelectDestination, StartScraping)
- 1 ProgressBar (ScrapeProgress)

The code is as follows:

```
Imports System.Net
Imports System.IO

Public Class Form1
Private moviedetails As String = Nothing
Private searchdir As String = Nothing
Private savedir As String = Nothing
Private errorlist As String = Nothing
Private successful As Integer = 0
Private total As Integer = 0

Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles SelectSource.Click
    Dim fb As New FolderBrowserDialog
    fb.Description = "Select the Folder"
    fb.RootFolder = Environment.SpecialFolder.MyComputer
    Dim dlgResult As DialogResult = fb.ShowDialog()

    If dlgResult = Windows.Forms.DialogResult.OK Then
        searchdir = fb.SelectedPath
        Dim di As New DirectoryInfo(searchdir)
        Dim fiArr As FileInfo() = di.GetFiles()
        NumberOfMovies.Text = "Number of movies in directory: " & fiArr.Count
    End If
End Sub

Private Sub Button2_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles StartScraping.Click
    total = 0
    successful = 0
    moviedetails = Nothing
    WriteConsolus("Initiating connection to database.")
    If searchdir IsNot Nothing And savedir IsNot Nothing Then
        Dim di As New DirectoryInfo(searchdir)
        Dim fiArr As FileInfo() = di.GetFiles()
        Dim fri As FileInfo
        Dim classif As String = Nothing
        Dim time As String = Nothing
        Dim genre As String = Nothing
        Dim plot As String = Nothing
        Dim rating As String = Nothing
        Dim mtitle() As String = New String() {"Nothing", "Nothing"}
        Dim myear() As String = New String() {"Nothing", "Nothing"}

        Dim dstring As String = "Nothing" & Chr(34) & "Nothing"
        Dim dar As String() = dstring.Split(Chr(34))

        Dim file As System.IO.File
        Dim write As System.IO.StreamWriter
        write = file.CreateText(savedir)
        write.WriteLine("{\rtf1")
        WriteConsolus("Starting read from " & searchdir)

        ScrapeProgress.Maximum = fiArr.Count
        ScrapeProgress.Value = 0

        For Each fri In fiArr
            Try
                Dim fn As String = fri.Name
                Dim fd As String = fri.Directory.Name

                Dim webclient As New WebClient
                WriteConsolus("")
                WriteConsolus("--------------------------------------------------------------------------------")
                WriteConsolus("~> " & fn & " <~")
                fn = fn.Replace(fri.Extension.ToString, "")
                fn = RemoveUnneededData(fn)

                If fn.Contains("(") And fn.Contains(")") Then
                    mtitle = fn.Split("(")
                    myear = fn.Split("(")
                    myear = myear(1).Split(")")
                    mtitle(0).Replace(myear(0), "")
                    WriteConsolus(" + Accessing " & "http://www.omdbapi.com/?t=" & mtitle(0) & "&y=" & myear(0))
                    dstring = webclient.DownloadString("http://www.omdbapi.com/?t=" & mtitle(0) & "&y=" & myear(0))
                    dar = dstring.Split(Chr(34))
                    classif = dar(11)
                    time = dar(19)
                    genre = dar(23)
                    plot = dar(39)
                    rating = dar(47)
                    successful = successful + 1
                Else
                    If fn.Contains("[") And fn.Contains("]") Then
                        mtitle = fn.Split("[")
                        myear = fn.Split("[")
                        myear = myear(1).Split("]")
                        mtitle(0).Replace(myear(0), "")
                        WriteConsolus(" + Accessing " & "http://www.omdbapi.com/?t=" & mtitle(0) & "&y=" & myear(0))
                        dstring = webclient.DownloadString("http://www.omdbapi.com/?t=" & mtitle(0) & "&y=" & myear(0))
                        dar = dstring.Split(Chr(34))
                        classif = dar(11)
                        time = dar(19)
                        genre = dar(23)
                        plot = dar(39)
                        rating = dar(47)
                        successful = successful + 1
                    Else
                        If System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex.IsMatch(fn, "([0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9])") Then
                            Dim mtemp As String() = fn.Split(" ")
                            myear(0) = mtemp.Last
                            mtitle(0) = Nothing
                            For Each z As String In mtemp
                                If z IsNot mtemp.Last Then
                                    mtitle(0) = mtitle(0) & z & " "
                                Else
                                    Exit For
                                End If
                            Next
                            WriteConsolus(" + Accessing " & "http://www.omdbapi.com/?t=" & mtitle(0) & "&y=" & myear(0))
                            dstring = webclient.DownloadString("http://www.omdbapi.com/?t=" & mtitle(0) & "&y=" & myear(0))
                            dar = dstring.Split(Chr(34))
                            classif = dar(11)
                            time = dar(19)
                            genre = dar(23)
                            plot = dar(39)
                            rating = dar(47)
                            successful = successful + 1
                        Else
                            If IsNumeric(fd) OrElse fd.Length = 9 Then
                                mtitle = fn.Split(".")
                                Dim tdf As Integer
                                Dim tdf2 As Integer
                                If fd.Length <> 4 Then
                                    tdf = CInt(fd.Substring(0, 4))
                                    tdf2 = CInt(fd.Substring(5, 4))
                                    WriteConsolus("Testing multiple year ranges...")
                                    For c As Integer = tdf To tdf2
                                        WriteConsolus(" + Testing " & c.ToString)
                                        myear(0) = c
                                        mtitle(0).Replace(myear(0), "")
                                        WriteConsolus("   - Accessing " & "http://www.omdbapi.com/?t=" & mtitle(0) & "&y=" & myear(0))
                                        dstring = webclient.DownloadString("http://www.omdbapi.com/?t=" & mtitle(0) & "&y=" & myear(0))
                                        dar = dstring.Split(Chr(34))
                                        classif = dar(11)
                                        time = dar(19)
                                        genre = dar(23)
                                        plot = dar(39)
                                        rating = dar(47)
                                    Next
                                Else
                                    myear(0) = fd
                                    mtitle(0).Replace(myear(0), "")
                                    WriteConsolus(" + Accessing " & "http://www.omdbapi.com/?t=" & mtitle(0) & "&y=" & myear(0))
                                    dstring = webclient.DownloadString("http://www.omdbapi.com/?t=" & mtitle(0) & "&y=" & myear(0))
                                    dar = dstring.Split(Chr(34))
                                    classif = dar(11)
                                    time = dar(19)
                                    genre = dar(23)
                                    plot = dar(39)
                                    rating = dar(47)
                                End If
                                successful = successful + 1
                            Else
                                mtitle = fn.Split(".")
                                WriteConsolus(" + Accessing " & "http://www.omdbapi.com/?t=" & mtitle(0))
                                dstring = webclient.DownloadString("http://www.omdbapi.com/?t=" & mtitle(0))
                                dar = dstring.Split(Chr(34))
                                classif = dar(11)
                                time = dar(19)
                                genre = dar(23)
                                plot = dar(39)
                                rating = dar(47)
                                myear(0) = dar(15)
                                successful = successful + 1
                            End If
                        End If
                    End If
                End If

                write.WriteLine("Title: " & dar(3) & " Year: " & myear(0) & " Classification: " & classif)
                write.WriteLine("\par")
                write.WriteLine("Time: " & time & " Genre: " & genre & " IMDb Rating: " & rating & vbCrLf)
                write.WriteLine("\par")
                write.WriteLine("Plot Summary: " & plot & vbCrLf & vbCrLf)
                write.WriteLine("\par")
                write.WriteLine("\par")
                WriteConsolus(" + Retrieved Data!")
            Catch ex As Exception
                Try
                    WriteConsolus(" + Movie not found in year. Attempting to search for just movie title.")
                    Dim fn As String = fri.Name
                    Dim fd As String = fri.Directory.Name
                    Dim webclient As New WebClient
                    myear(0) = Nothing
                    fn = fn.Replace(fri.Extension.ToString, "")
                    fn = RemoveUnneededData(fn)
                    If fn.Contains("(") And fn.Contains(")") Then
                        mtitle = fn.Split("(")
                    Else
                        If fn.Contains("[") And fn.Contains("]") Then
                            mtitle = fn.Split("[")
                        Else
                            If System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex.IsMatch(fn, "([0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9])") Then
                                Dim mtemp As String() = fn.Split(" ")
                                myear(0) = mtemp.Last
                                mtitle(0) = Nothing
                                For Each z As String In mtemp
                                    If z IsNot mtemp.Last Then
                                        mtitle(0) = mtitle(0) & z & " "
                                    Else
                                        Exit For
                                    End If
                                Next
                            Else
                                If IsNumeric(fd) Then
                                    mtitle = fn.Split(".")
                                End If
                            End If
                        End If
                    End If
                    WriteConsolus(" + Accessing " & "http://www.omdbapi.com/?t=" & mtitle(0))
                    dstring = webclient.DownloadString("http://www.omdbapi.com/?t=" & mtitle(0))
                    dar = dstring.Split(Chr(34))
                    classif = dar(11)
                    time = dar(19)
                    genre = dar(23)
                    plot = dar(39)
                    rating = dar(47)
                    myear(0) = dar(15)
                    WriteConsolus(" + Title search successful!")
                    successful = successful + 1

                    write.WriteLine("Title: " & dar(3) & " Year: " & myear(0) & " Classification: " & classif)
                    write.WriteLine("\par")
                    write.WriteLine("Time: " & time & " Genre: " & genre & " IMDb Rating: " & rating & vbCrLf)
                    write.WriteLine("\par")
                    write.WriteLine("Plot Summary: " & plot & vbCrLf & vbCrLf)
                    write.WriteLine("\par")
                    write.WriteLine("SCRAPED USING AN AMBIGUOUS METHOD! MAY REQUIRE DOUBLE CHECKING!")
                    write.WriteLine("\par")
                    write.WriteLine("\par")
                    WriteConsolus(" + Retrieved Data!")
                Catch ex2 As Exception
                    If dar(3) = False And dar(7) = "Movie not found!" Then
                        WriteConsolus(" + Movie was not found, please do a manual lookup by:")
                        WriteConsolus("   - Doing a manual search on IMDb.com")
                        WriteConsolus("   - Or searching on Google.com")
                        moviedetails = moviedetails & "Failed to read: " & fri.Name & " Location: " & fri.FullName & " Reason: Movie not found! Please do a manual lookup!" & "\par" & ex.Message & "\par" & " " & "\par" & " "
                    Else
                        WriteConsolus(ex.Message)
                        moviedetails = moviedetails & "Failed to read: " & fri.Name & " Location: " & fri.FullName & " Reason: " & ex.Message & "\par" & "Variables at time of failure: " & mtitle(0) & "[Title]" & myear(0) & "[Year]" & "\par" & " " & "\par" & " "
                    End If
                    'WriteConsolus("Movie was not found, please do a manual lookup! (Movie might have different name.)")
                    'moviedetails = moviedetails & "Failed to read: " & fri.Name & " Location: " & fri.FullName & " Reason: Movie not found! Please do a manual lookup!" & "\par" & ex.Message & "\par" & " " & "\par" & " "
                End Try

            End Try
            WriteConsolus("--------------------------------------------------------------------------------")
            total = total + 1
            ScrapeProgress.Value += 1
            PercentComplete.Text = Int(ScrapeProgress.Value / ScrapeProgress.Maximum * 100) & "%"
            NumberOfSuccessful.Text = "Number of successful scrapes: " & successful.ToString & " of " & total.ToString
        Next fri
        write.WriteLine("}")
        write.Close()
        WriteConsolus("")
        WriteConsolus("Finished! RTF File created at " & savedir)
        If moviedetails IsNot Nothing Then
            write = file.CreateText(errorlist)
            write.WriteLine("{\rtf1")
            moviedetails.Replace("\", "/")
            write.Write(moviedetails)
            write.Write("Please change the filename manually and rerun!")
            write.WriteLine("}")
            write.Close()
            WriteConsolus("There were errors reading some files. Please check " & errorlist & " for details.")
        Else
            WriteConsolus("No errors reading filenames.")
        End If
        WriteConsolus("")
        WriteConsolus(">>>>> DISCLAIMER <<<<<")
        WriteConsolus("")
        WriteConsolus("Please note that the results for these movies are NOT from IMDb!")
        WriteConsolus("They are provided by OMDBAPI.com.")
        WriteConsolus("Any likeness of results to persons deceased or living is coincidental!")
        WriteConsolus("")
        WriteConsolus("Distributed as open source by Asryael - http://stackoverflow.com/users/1808539/asryael.")
    Else
        WriteConsolus("No destination and source folders selected!!!")
    End If

End Sub

Private Sub Button3_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles SelectDestination.Click
    Dim fb As New SaveFileDialog
    fb.Filter = "RTF Files(*.rtf)|*.rtf|All files (*.*)|*.*"
    fb.FilterIndex = 1
    Dim dlgResult As DialogResult = fb.ShowDialog()

    If dlgResult = Windows.Forms.DialogResult.OK Then
        savedir = fb.FileName
        errorlist = fb.FileName.Remove(fb.FileName.LastIndexOf(".")) & " - Failed Reads.rtf"
    End If
End Sub

Private Sub WriteConsolus(text As String)
    Consolus.AppendText(text & vbCrLf)
    Consolus.SelectionStart = Consolus.Text.Length
    Consolus.ScrollToCaret()
End Sub

Public Function RemoveUnneededData(text As String) As String
text = text.Replace(".", " ")
text = text.Replace("720p", "")
text = text.Replace("1080p", "")
text = text.Replace(" CD1", "")
text = text.Replace(" CD2", "")
text = text.Replace("-CD1", "")
text = text.Replace("-CD2", "")
text = text.Replace("CD1", "")
text = text.Replace("CD2", "")
text = text.Replace("-cd1", "")
text = text.Replace("-cd2", "")
text = text.Replace(" cd1", "")
text = text.Replace(" cd2", "")
text = text.Replace("cd1", "")
text = text.Replace("cd2", "")
text = text.Replace(" dvd1", "")
text = text.Replace(" dvd2", "")
text = text.Replace("-dvd1", "")
text = text.Replace("-dvd2", "")
text = text.Replace("dvd1", "")
text = text.Replace("dvd2", "")
Return text
End Function
End Class
```

That's it. That's all you need for it to work. Simply select the source folder with all your movies in it, then your destination file and hit begin! Please note that it is done `synchronously` which means there may be some delay with the UI.

Any updates or changes to the code is welcomed! I'm always wanting to improve my knowledge!

Comment: Instead of prepopulating your arrays like this: `Dim mtitle() As String = "Nothing Nothing".Split(" ")`, which requires parsing the string at runtime, it is easier and more efficient to use an array literal, like this:  `Dim mtitle() As String = New String() { "Nothing", "Nothing" }`.

Comment: Also, you are doing all those replaces twice.  It seems like that's a good opportunity to break that logic out into a separate method.